# How to retrieve AD groups and members in power bi?

Tags: active-directory, powerbi, powerquery

I have a report with a matrix, where I want to further drill down AD groups into members:

[image]

I know there is an AD source,

My goal is to connect my table which has column '**AD group**' with a table that has: **AD group**, **Member** columns.

(the relationship shall be "many to many")

How can I achieve this?

(the AD source has cryptic names, so its hard to navigate).

[image]